# Combine or Simplify Web Service Queries in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I was wondering if there was a flexible way to setup multiple web services (API) queries in Power BI. The web service I am using is only capable of getting me one day of data for one location per query and I need daily data for 10 locations. Which means on a standard 31 day month I would need to setup 310 queries. The data I am interested in are the Final LMPs and the website I am pulling from is https://webservices.iso-ne.com/docs/v1.1/. An example of a working query in PowerBI that is grabbing Final LMP data for just 02/01/2020 for location 4152 is:

`https://webservices.iso-ne.com/api/v1.1/hourlylmp/rt/final/day/20200201/location/4152.xml`

Comment: You could use a parameter and some formatting to drive the 20200201 part. then you only have to do the 10 queries and run them each day.

Comment: ^ the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

For such case I would setup the following items:

1. A data source (e.g. manually via 'Enter Data') with 10 individual locations
2. A data source with the required date range (e.g. something like [that](https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/07/23/fill-dates-between-dates-with-power-bi-power-query/))
3. A data source that combines the the first two (cross join e.g. [an example](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/cross-join-with-power-query/))
4. Add a column (to source 3) that calls a 'custom function' that for each combined record (in step 3) makes an API request to retrieve the data. The function should take two parameters (location and the day) as the input

Thanks,
Mau

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create 10 queries, for each of the locations, you can then use a variable to drive the date of extraction.

In the advanced editor after the 'let' add

```
var_date = Date.ToText(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),  "yyyyMMdd")
```

Which today will return 20200221. When the query runs it will evaluate it and run it for the right day.

```
https://webservices.iso-ne.com/api/v1.1/hourlylmp/rt/final/day/20200201/location/4152.xml
```

Change to in your source to something like:

```
"https://webservices.iso-ne.com/api/v1.1/hourlylmp/rt/final/day/" & var_date & "/location/4152.xml"
```

So it should be like this:

[image]

If you need to offset the date try `DateTime.FixedLocalNow() -1` to get the previous day.